# Quick tests for Self complementary vertex transitive graphs

Tags: computational-complexity, graph-theory

Are there any quick tests to determine if a graph is Self complementary vertex transitive? That is if the graph is self complementary vertex transitive the answer should be yes.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly comprehensive survey as of 13 years ago is given in [Alastair Farrugia's Master's thesis](http://www.alastairfarrugia.net/sc-graph/sc-graph-survey.pdf)  (see chapter 3, in particular).

Comment: I don't see an answer to the question, though.  I think the answer is that nobody knows.  My guess is that it is equivalent to graph isomorphism.

Comment: Unlikely to be same as GI. Lot of algebraic structure in the involved graphs if answer to input in Yes.